# Inserting a Japanese XML feed in to a MYSQL table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been looking for a solution to this issue and have tried most answers found. But with no luck was I able to insert the Japanese xml feed into the tables which have been created.

I tried setting all setting where UTF8 should be used as most answers have suggested - But no luck!!

Comment: There isn't much information in this question as to what precisely is going wrong. Do you see a MySQL error message? Is anything at all inserted? If anything is inserted, how does it deviate from what you expected?

Comment: The php script I'm using seems to be fine, as I have duplicated it to be used for other XML feeds in English. 

But when I try using the php script for other foreign characters or languages, I seem to either be getting messed up characters inserted into the fields even when I have adjusted the charset to UTF8.

But for the Japanese characters, nothing gets inserted what so ever!

Could it be a problem with the current settings or do I have to adjust the collation of the tables where the Japanese text is supposed to be inserted into or could it be the php phrase script needs to be altered.

Answer (score 0):

- Check that the connection character set is UTF-8 by making it issue `SET NAMES utf8` as the first task it does.
- Check that the page you are using to view the data is marked as UTF-8: do this either by sending a content-type header that specifies UTF-8, or by adding a meta tag that says so (I'm sorry, I don't know much about XML so I don't know how it is done).
- Check that the data you are receiving is encoded as UTF-8. If it is encoded in some other character set but you are presenting it to MySQL as UTF-8, then it may get stored mis-encoded in the database, or MySQL may make the best sense of it that it can and garble/truncate it as a result.